# How to get the wi-fi connection status from terminal?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, sleep-wake

Sometimes, when waking up my mac, I get the message "Alert: No internet connection" on the Wi-Fi icon. I can solve it everytime by turning Wi-Fi off and on again. **Is there a terminal command I can use to detect the current connection status?** I would like to run a script to turn Wi-Fi off and on automatically on waking up if so. Other solutions are welcome, too.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a script for tuning the WiFi on and connecting you, the OS X system does that already for you. If you look in Console (look for line containing Airport) and the lines after that will show it in action.
Best is if you could publish that log in here to see why is it not working for you.

Here are some choices for you:

1. If you want a Scrip to continuously test if you are connected you could use this:

   repeat
       try
           do shell script "ping -c 5 google.com"
       on error
           display dialog "You are not connected to the internet"
       end try
   end repeat
2. One of the simplest Terminal commands to see if you are connected and all connections that are active is the `Netstat`.
3. To see the details of your current connection use `Airport-I` in Terminal.
4. Now if you want to use the Terminal to connect to your WiFi use following:

Manually connect to WiFi

Turn On

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Turn OFF `networksetup -setairportpower en0 off`

Find

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
```

Connect

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
```

If you do not know it use the Find the SSID- BSSID

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -s
```

5. Finlay, if you do this frequently create a script in Apple Script app.

Save the following apple script as application. Pull it to your dock for fast access.

```
--
-- Toggle Airport Power On and Off
--
if (offset of "On" in (do shell script "networksetup -getairportpower en0")) > 0 then
    do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en0 off"
else
    do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en0 on"
end if
```

Comment: it looks like he wants to turn off wifi and turn it back on via a shell command in the terminal.  Wit the router I have at work this is sometimes necessary to reconnect to the wifi network.